# getting data from browser with socket.on method on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

With nodejs I'm streaming data to client/browser and listing them without any problem. What I wanted to do was sending back some of the ids to the server by clicking on them. Anyway here is my code. I hope you would tell what I'm doing wrong in this case.

**Server Side**

```
var socketServer = io.listen(server);
socketServer.set('log level', 1); //don't log all emits etc

socketServer.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('New connection logged');
    socketServer.sockets.emit('data', t.globalState);
});

//This is not working!
//I tried to put it in different places, no changes!
socketServer.sockets.on('hello', function(data) {
    console.log('Hello!');
}); 

socketServer.sockets.on('close', function(socket) {
    console.log('socketServer has closed');
});

var t = new conwit(config.conwit);

t.openStream = function () {
    console.log('Opening Stream');
    t.createStream();
};
t.createStream = function () {

    t.stream('statuses/filter', {
        track: t.globalState.tags,
        language: config.language
    }, function(stream) {

                stream.on('data', t.emitT);
                stream.on('error', function(error) {
                    console.log("My error: ", error);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        t.openStream();
                    }, 30000);

                });

    });

};

t.emitT = function (data) {
        console.log(' receiving');
        if (data.text !== undefined) {
            socketServer.sockets.emit('data', data);
        }
};

t.openStream();

return t;

};
```

**Browser Side**

```
TM.socket.on('data', function(msg) {
   alert('News from server: ' + msg); //this works
   TM.socket.emit('hello', {msg:'Hello server'}); //this doesn't work!
});

$('#send').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    TM.socket.emit('hello', { //this doesn't work
        rF: "foo",
        rT: "zazz",
        ea: "limk"
    });
});
```

There is no error/log messages on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your server code to this:

```
var socketServer = io.listen(server);
// Are you sure you have instantiated the config variable you use here?
var t = new conwit(config.conwit);
socketServer.set('log level', 1); //don't log all emits etc

// Every time a socket connects to the server, this callback executes.
// Notice that there is a convenient 'socket' variable to use as a 
// handle for this specific socket.
socketServer.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('New connection logged');

    socketServer.sockets.emit('data', t.globalState);

    // This broadcasts the message to all the sockets (including the current 
    // one)
    socketServer.sockets.emit('data', 'Hey everybody! A new client has connected!')

    // This broadcasts the message to all the sockets but not the current
    // one
    socket.broadcast.emit('data', 'Hey everybody! A new client has connected!')

    // Now when a specific socket emits the 'hello' event, this callback will
    // execute...
    socket.on('hello', function(data) {
       console.log('Hello!');
       // ...and it will send a 'data' event back to the socket
       socket.emit('data', 'Hello client! This is your server speaking.');
    });

    // ...add more socket and/or t events here
});
```

Notice that there are three ways to communicate with your sockets;

1. **socketServer.sockets.emit(event_name, event_data):** This emits an event to ALL the  connected sockets, including the one that fired the event. For example assume a red button on a web page that is bound with this code:

   `socket.emit('red button clicked');`

   Then, on your server you have this code:

   `socket.on('red button clicked', function() {
       socketServer.sockets.emit('boom', 'A user clicked the red button');
   });`

   Every time a user clicks on the button on the page, ALL the clients (including the one who clicked on the button) will receive a the event 'boom'.
2. **socket.broadcast.emit(event_name, event_data):** This is the same as above with the only difference that ALL the clients will receive the event, except the one who clicked on the button.
3. **socket.emit(event_name, event_data):** This will only send the 'boom' event to the client who clicked on the button.

For more information refer to the [Socket.IO documentation](http://socket.io/docs/).

Comment: That worked like a charm. I missed the **socket** variable in socketServer.sockets.on('connection', function(**socket**) for current one. And yes **config.conwit** is passed correctly.